# A explicit basis for the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of rational function $\mathbb{C}(z)$.

Tags: field-theory

What would be a basis for this space? We know that for just the $\mathbb{C}[z]$ we have the basis to be $1, x, x^2, \ldots$. But when looking at the fraction field of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ does it still have the same basis? What about the monomials of the form $1/x^{n}$ for all $n$? Should they be considered in the basis as well? Instincts told me yes.

Comment: How would you express $\frac{1}{2x+1}$ in your new proposed basis?

Comment: I think any basis has to be uncountable, since you need to have at least all of the fractions of the form $\frac{1}{z - \alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: partial fraction decomposition.